# Why is the x86 CR1 control register reserved?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture

Starting with the i386 CPU, Intel processors have exposed *control registers* to allow the kernel to configure the processor and specify characteristics of the currently executing task/process/thread. According to the [Intel Systems Programming Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html) (section 2-13), the `CR1` control register is "Reserved". That is, the kernel manipulating control register `CR1` results in undefined behavior. As the articles indicates, there are also `CR2, CR3, CR4` and `CR8` control registers, though they are **not** reserved.

**Why is `CR1` reserved?** It is strange that Intel would introduce a reserved control register, and then start adding non-reserved control registers thereafter rather than simply adding functionality to `CR1` as doing so would not cause any backwards compatibility breaks (that's the whole point of keeping it reserved). http://www.pagetable.com/?p=364 speculates that `CR1` was kept reserved to have a second register available for architectural configuration, but as the article mentions, `CR4` was used instead when the i486 was introduced.

Comment: Another interesting question is why there are no CR5-7 control registers, but in the interest of keeping this question from devolving into a general discussion on hardware design, I've kept it out of scope.

Comment: I've often wondered this as well. I suspect you'll never find a non-speculative answer though.

Comment: I have no idea what actually happened here, but normally when you see something like this being "reserved", it's because it *used* to do something, but that functionality has been removed. It's very common for function parameters or struct members in API documentation, for example. Also, don't be so quick to assume that just because something is documented as being "reserved" means that changing it won't result in backwards incompatibilities. Developers aren't well known for playing by the rules!

Comment: The CR5-7 missing thing is easy to unfold: `mov r64, cr8` is just `REX.R + mov r64, cr0` and it was AMD that used the REX prefix to open eight new control registers exactly because Intel reserved CR5-7 and AMD didn't "own" them. One could now speculate if CR8-15 are AMD reserved and CR1,5-7 are Intel reserved.

Comment: Maybe Intel planned to use CR1 as an extension of CR0. CR0 is essentially a bit-set while CR2 and CR3 contain addresses. So conceptually the first two registers could have been used to hold flags while the other two a single address each. That would make sense if not for CR4, which again contains flags.

Comment: Yep, this is never going to be answered. I actually got to the point where I  was going to discuss the matter with Intel over an NDA, but they decided to keep it confidential. Oh well

Answer (score 3):

The *[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)* says *CR1 — Reserved*. So CR1 is unused and reserved to Intel + AMD for future use. Since it is reserved, accessing CR1 throws an exception:

> Attempts to reference CR1, CR5, CR6, CR7, and CR9–CR15 result in
>   undefined opcode (#UD) exceptions.

Why they haven't used CR1 when they have used CR2 is anyone's guess. X86 is irregular and indeed, Intel hasn't said anything. This article 
[Why is there no CR1 – and why are control registers such a mess anyway?](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=364) has some history but really unless Intel says something official, and they haven't, there is no answer.